# Java export csv from server to clients that may not be on same OS

Tags: java, windows, unix, csv

If I have an application sitting on a *nix box and I generate a csv that is then passed off to thin client users what precautions must I take if they are on Windows and want a proper csv?

What I mean is this flow:

UNIX:
1) Generate csv using `System.getProperty("line.separator")`
2) Pass to thin client

Windows/Unix:
1) Download file from browser
2a) Open in Excel (Windows)
2b) Open in some spreadsheet application

I am not looking for answers that say use `Library X`, there is a lack of fondness for adding technical risk for libraries that are used for only one project.

Comment: You might want to check out RFC-4180 <http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180> to ensure that you are meeting the CSV specification.  Of course, some of the programs that might be processing your file might not follow the spec completely and/or correctly, either.

Comment: @SteveValliere good read, just wanted to make sure I was following some known implementation.  Looks like I should do "\r\n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [rfc4180 section 2][1]

> there is no formal    specification in existence, which allows for a
> wide variety of    interpretations of CSV files.  This section
> documents the format that    seems to be followed by most
> implementations:
>
> 1. Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line
>    break (CRLF).  For example:
>
>    aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF
> 2. The last record in the file may or may not have an ending line
>    break.  For example:
>
>    aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
> 3. There maybe an optional header line appearing as the first line
>    of the file with the same format as normal record lines.  This
>    header will contain names corresponding to the fields in the file
>    and should contain the same number of fields as the records in
>    the rest of the file (the presence or absence of the header line
>    should be indicated via the optional "header" parameter of this
>    MIME type).  For example:
>
>    field_name,field_name,field_name CRLF
>    aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF

Therefore `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is incorrect and `\r\n` should be used instead.
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2